# Advantage Database server crash

Tags: crash, advantage-database-server

The following query makes an Advantage Database Server crash:

```
SELECT +SUM(0) FROM SYSTEM.IOTA
```

Note the `+` before `SUM(0)`, this is the culprit.
If I replace `+` by `-`, no error occurs.

If I execute this query in local mode, this error pops up:

```
poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2203;  
[iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]
An error was encountered while reading an intermediate or temporary file.
```

I discovered the problem while testing and, even if I agree there is no point to add a `+` before an aggregation instruction, it should not crash the server!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is confirmed to be a bug. The combination of the unary positive operator and the aggregate function is the cause of the problem. It will be fixed in a future update.